# Excel VB Convert sheet text to unicode chars

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010, vbscript, visual-basic

I need to enter a function in an excel sheet that converts all cells values, that are texts, to it Unicode values.

For example I want `ü` to be `&#252;` and so on.

How can I achieve this, is it possible?

Comment: I'm confused. If it's already in unicode, why would you need to convert it to unicode? Some documentation [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-HA010167539.aspx)

Comment: @Raystafarian: It seems that RaduM wants HTML `&#` entities and the website automatically "unconverted" their example.

Comment: @grawity Ah, the questions has clarified that now

Answer (score 1):

Try this

### FORMULA

```
="&#"&CODE(A2)&";"
```

### OUTPUT

```
&#252;
```

Here `CELL A2` contains `"ü"`

Comment: LOL Siva, that was really easy, but I need to parse the text that contains those characters for example ülorem will convert to a number and I only need to convert ü.